# Move text to the left on jsp page with html

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am trying to move the text "first name" and "last name" for the textbooks to the left and align it with the header. I use two radio buttons one to show the text boxes and one to hide them. I tried align="left" and style but it did not work.

```
<tr>
<td class="odd" width="20%" nowrap>
    <bean:message key="editvarref.header.name"/>
</td>
<td class="odd" width="80%">
    <div>
       <html:radio styleId="users_name_type_0" property="user_type" value="Show" onclick="getResults(this)" />
        <label for="user_name_type_0"><bean:message key="input.use.name"/></label>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
        <html:radio styleId="no_name_type_1" property="user_type" value="Nothing" onclick="getResults(this)" />
        <label for="no_name_type_1"><bean:message key="no.use.name"/></label>
    </div>

    <div class="text">
        <p>First Name:
            <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30">
         </p>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>Last Name:
            <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30">
         </p>
     </div>

</td>
```

Is there a way I can align the values of First Name:" and "Last Name:" with  editvarref.header.name which is  "User Information:"

**UPDATE**

[image]

How would i move the first name and last name to the left and align it with User Information in addition to aligning the text boxes with the radio buttons.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUggI.png

Comment: put your code in a fiddle. we need to see how it looks like now.

Comment: @Ji_in_coding i could get it in a fiddle but i took a screen shot, check update

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: no bootstrap @QuentinTanioartino

Answer (score 1):

Without making too much changes to your html structure,
I would suggest moving your title into the same td as your radio/input.

I have put the [sample code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbxYNr) on codepen. You will see your orignal design and the modified design. The css applies to the modified design.

html:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="odd" width="20%" nowrap>

    </td>
    <td class="odd" width="80%">
      <h2>User Information</h2>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="users_name_type_0" />
        <label for="user_name_type_0">Input User Info</label>
      </div>
      <div style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
        <input type="radio" id="users_name_type_0" />
        <label for="no_name_type_1">Input Later</label>
      </div>

      <div class="text">
        <label for="text1">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <label for="text2">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" maxlength="30">
      </div>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.table{
  width: 600px;
}

.text label{
  display: block;
}
```

Edit:

I have replaced your jsp tags with corresponding html elements so that they show up correctly in codepen.